# How to enforce the boundary conditions

Tags: finite-element, unstructured-mesh

I want to solve a poisson problem on two domains,(interface problem: Let $\Omega $ be a square, $\Omega=\Omega1 \cup \Omega2$ and let $\Omega1$  be a circle inside the square.
$\Gamma$ is the boundary of circle.
$$\Delta u_1=f_1 ~~in ~~\Omega1$$
$$\Delta u_2=f_2 ~~in ~~\Omega2$$
$$u_2=g~~on ~~\partial \Omega$$
$$u_2-u_1=w ~~on~~\Gamma$$
$$\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial n_2}-\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial n_1}=v~~on~~\Gamma$$

What should  I do  by the conditions on $\Gamma$, they are boundary conditions? 
If yes, How to enforce these conditions, when the test space is $H^1(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions on $\Gamma$ are called interface conditions. You could incorporate the jump conditions into your weak form. Typically, the trial and test spaces are $H^{1}(\Omega_{1}) \times H^{1}(\Omega_{2})$. Numerically, the interfacial condition is easier to treat if $\Gamma$ is aligned with a mesh of $\Omega$. One example of how you might treat the embedded interface condition can be found in Chapter 4 of the [PhD thesis by Chandrasekhar Annavarapu](http://dukespace.lib.duke.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/10161/7213/AnnavarapuSrinivas_duke_0066D_11894.pdf?sequence=1), out of John Dolbow's group at Duke.